# seach for a word in .txt files and write few line into new .txt file

Tags: script, batch-file, vbscript, parsing

Please help me to create a script to perform task as per described below. i have 2 files. A.txt and B.txt
Content of A.txt as per below

---

```
ITEM

name TICKY

title nice coffe drink

type DRINK

ITEM

name APPLE

title sweet tasty apple

type FRUIT

ITEM

name JUICE

title nice tasty drink

type DRINK

ITEM

name ORANG

title niice nice orange

type FRUIT

ITEM

name CHERY

title nutritious rich fruit

type FRUIT
```

---

now i need to search in A.txt for word "FRUIT", and the copy the 2nd line on top of the "FRUIT" to a new file named

list.txt. BUT i only need the name of the fruit, where the list.txt should be looks like below.

```
APPLE

ORANG

CHERY
```

---

This is my coding (powel shel) to do this...

---

```
$source = "C:\temp\A.txt"

$destination = "C:\temp\list.txt"

$hits = select-string -Path $source -SimpleMatch "type FRUIT" -CaseSensitive

$filecontents = get-content $source

foreach($hit in $hits)

{

    $filecontents[$hit.linenumber-3]| out-file -append $destination

    "" |out-file -append $destination

}
```

---

This will extract the 2nd top line as per below

```
name APPLE

name ORANG

name CHERY
```

And below coding (.bat) wil remove the word "name".

---

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

del list2.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (C:\temp\list.txt) do (

  set line=%%a

  set chars=!line:~-13,13!

  echo !chars! >> list2.txt

)
```

---

As 2nd phase, now i need to search for word in the list.txt file (APPLE,ORANG,CHERY.....) in my B.txt.. B.txt wil be

looks as per below.

---

```
ITEM

p_date 10/03/15

pt_time 11:29:40:00

title nice coffe drink

name TICKY

stock yes

end

ITEM

p_date 10/03/15

pt_time 11:29:40:00

title sweet tasty apple

name APPLE

stock yes

end

ITEM

p_date 10/03/15

pt_time 11:29:40:00

title nice tasty drink

name JUICE

stock yes

end

ITEM

p_date 10/03/15

pt_time 11:29:40:00

title niice nice orange

name ORANG

stock yes

end

ITEM

p_date 10/03/15

pt_time 11:29:40:00

title nutritious rich fruit

name CHERY

stock yes

end
```

---

And now, i must serch for the worlds from list.txt in B.txt, and extract the 3 top line and write it accordingly in new file

named done.txt ............ below is my coding (powershel).

---

```
$source = "C:\temp\B.txt"

$destination = "C:\temp\done.txt"

$patterns = Get-Content c:\temp\list2.txt | Where-Object{$_}

$results = Select-String c:\temp\done.txt -Pattern $patterns -SimpleMatch

$results.Line | ForEach-Object{"$_`r`n"} | Set-Content c:\temp\done.txt

foreach($hit in $hits)

{

    $filecontents[$hit.linenumber-4]| out-file -append $destination

    $filecontents[$hit.linenumber-3]| out-file -append $destination

    $filecontents[$hit.linenumber-2]| out-file -append $destination

    $filecontents[$hit.linenumber-1]| out-file -append $destination

    "" |out-file -append $destination

}
```

---

I managed to develop coding for this. but i need 3 script file (2 powershel and 1 batch) to complete this operation. Kindly

assist me to complete this task in one single script. It wil be best if it's in .vbs or .bat.
Please help me..thank you.